# Build Docker image with a future view of RPM upgrade

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, rpm

My aim is to build a docker image for my application, the core part of the application is installed through RPM during the image build.

Suppose I've built my docker image with 'application-version-1.rpm' file and a container is running with this image. After one or two month back developers released a new rpm with patch 'application-version-2.rpm', I need to install/upgrade this rpm file inside the running container. as this container is running on production, how can I update my image with existing data and with the newly released rpm file. Any Idea on this.

Note: I need to stop an application service to install/upgrade the new rpm file. The Entrypoint in my docker image is the application service. So if I stop the application service, it will stop the container.

Comment: Why do you need to update inside of the running container? Solve this problem instead.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: Additionally, when you use OpenShift you can deploy new container and move traffic to a new container in a blink of an eye, so there will be no downtime.

Comment: This is not how docker is supposed to be used. Learn about treating servers as [cattle versus pets](https://medium.com/@Joachim8675309/devops-concepts-pets-vs-cattle-2380b5aab313).

Answer (score 1):

You basically never do software updates inside a running Docker container.  Instead, you build a new Docker image with the new software installed, stop the existing container, and start a new one with the new image.

```sh
docker run --name myapp ... myapp:1
# Time passes
docker build --no-cache -t myapp:2 .
docker stop myapp
docker rm myapp
docker run --name myapp ... myapp:2
```

Deleting containers like this is extremely routine, so if there's any data you care about you need to make sure it's stored outside the container using a `docker run -v` option.

If you're using Docker Compose as an orchestrator you might be able to `docker-compose stop` your existing container, then `docker-compose up --build` again; or you can rebuild the image manually with `docker build` and change the `image:` line in your `docker-compose.yml` file.  If you're using a Kubernetes Deployment, changing the `image:` in its pod spec will actually cause it to first start a new container (pod) then delete the old one, for a zero-downtime update.